# nothing is printing after running the below C code , nothing gets outputted

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, palindrome

nothing is printing after running the below C code , nothing gets outputted, I am not getting understand what is happening, please help.

This code checks if the string is palindrome or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *words[] = {"rar", "tokyo", "level", "prefix", "mom", "delhi", "naruto"};
int size = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);

void palindChecker(char **, int);

int main() {
    palindChecker(words, size);

    return 0;
}

void palindChecker(char **array, int len) {
    char tempStr[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        strcpy(tempStr, strrev(*(array + i)));
        if (strcmp(strrev(*(array + i)), tempStr) == 0) {
            printf("%s is palindrome\n", *(array + i));
        }
        else {
            printf("%s is not palindrome\n", *(array + i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `strrev` declared / defined?

Comment: Oh, now I see. Your program has undefined behavior. `char *words[] = {"rar", "tokyo", "level", "prefix", "mom", "delhi", "naruto"};` should be `const char *words[] = {"rar", "tokyo", "level", "prefix", "mom", "delhi", "naruto"};` - and you are not allowed to change those.

Comment: `*(array+i)` is more idiomatically written as `array[i]`.

Comment: `strrev()` is a nonstandard function. It modifies the string in place, so you can't use it with string literals. You should copy `array[i]` to `tempStr`, then reverse `tempStr`, rather than reversing `array[i]` itself.

Comment: You do not need temporary storage to check that a string is a palindrome.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Where is the UB corrected by the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72002983/nothing-is-printing-after-running-the-below-c-code-nothing-gets-outputted#comment127229160_72002983)?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The hope was that making them `const` would make it harder to try to change them.  One usually gets the compiler's support if trying to change a `const` variable. At least, that was the aim.

Comment: @TedLyngmo OK, so the suggested code change itself does not fix the UB, but hopefully highlights it.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, but I then wrote an answer to try to help fix the issue too.

Answer (score 2):

The issue:

- `strrev` makes changes to the string you supply to it, which means that you are making changes to string literals, which is not allowed. Your program may crash or do something else unexpected.

Suggestions:

- Don't try to make changes to the strings in the array. Instead, make the changes to `tempStr`.
- Declare the array using a `const` type to make it clear that you are not allowed to change the strings:

  ```c
  const char *words[] = {"rar", "tokyo", "level", "prefix",
                         "mom", "delhi", "naruto"};
  ```

Example:

```c
void palindChecker(const char *array[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char tempStr[strlen(array[i]) + 1];        // a VLA (optional compiler support)
        memcpy(tempStr, array[i], sizeof tempStr); // copy the original string

        if (strcmp(array[i], strrev(tempStr)) == 0) { // reverse `tempStr`
            printf("%s is palindrome\n", array[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%s is not palindrome\n", array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If your compiler does not support VLA:s (variable length arrays), `malloc`ing the appropriate memory could be an option:

```c
void palindChecker(const char *array[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        size_t len = strlen(array[i]) + 1;

        char *tempStr = malloc(len); // allocate space for the string + null terminator
        if(tempStr == NULL) {        // malloc failed
            perror("malloc");
            exit(1);
        }
        memcpy(tempStr, array[i], len);

        if (strcmp(array[i], strrev(tempStr)) == 0) {
            printf("%s is palindrome\n", array[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%s is not palindrome\n", array[i]);
        }

        free(tempStr);               // free the allocated memory
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, do not reverse the strings at all. Check if a string is a palindrome by just comparing the beginning with the end and "walk towards the middle":

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_palindrome(const char* str) {
    for (const char *b = str, *e = b + strlen(str); b < e--; ++b) {
        if(*b != *e) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void palindChecker(const char *array[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (is_palindrome(array[i])) {
            printf("%s is palindrome\n", array[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%s is not palindrome\n", array[i]);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: In C, string literals are not `const`. They are not modifiable, but their type is `char[N]`, not `const char[N]`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks, I always forget that since I see them as `const` :) Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

On re-loading I know see [@Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003307/2410359) good update with `is_palindrome(const char* str)`.

Leaving as *Community wiki* for reference.

---

> nothing gets outputted

`strrev(*(array + i)` attempts an in-place change of contents of a *string literal* like `"rar"`.  This leads to **undefined behavior** (UB) whihc includes *not printing*.  Re-code and avoid UB.

Instead consider not reversing the string at all and simple compare the end of a spring to the beginning.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_palindrome(const char *s) {
  const char *end = s;
  while (*end) {
    end++;
  }
  // end points to a null character.

  while (end > s) {
    --end;
    if (*end != *s) {
      return false;
    }
    s++;
  }
  return true;
}

void palindChecker(const char **array, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (is_palindrome(array[i]) {
      printf("%s is palindrome\n", *(array + i));
    }
    else {
      printf("%s is not palindrome\n", *(array + i));
    }
  }
}
```